# I have transferred USDT to ERS20 address of my crypto wallet but wrong missed the last char in address and its fund of about 800K

Tags: go-ethereum, addresses, usdt

From coinformat trading platform I transferred to my crypto.com wallet . But it looks I missed the last char in ERS20 address...

My actual address is
0xxxxxxxxxxx3B43dd72103372Ecc3B4Ff00eeCc3297

But now upon checking it is

0xxxxxxxxxxx3dd72103372Ecc3B4Ff00eeCc329

Looks I missed last digit .

It fund of about 800k USDT and it just happened now.. not sure how to proceed and retrieve it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to hear about your situation. Unfortunately, cryptocurrency transactions are irreversible, which means that once the funds have been sent to an incorrect address, it is almost impossible to recover them. However, there are a few steps you can take to try to recover your funds, such as contacting the customer support teams of the platforms involved and seeking advice from professionals in the cryptocurrency field. It's important to act quickly in this situation, as the longer you wait, the harder it may be to recover your funds. To be honest, the chances of recovering the funds are very low, but it's worth exploring all options available to you. Good luck and I hope you are able to resolve this issue.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , based on etherscan.io for my incorrect address I'm able to check that address is invalid it's because address not in expected format. Does this goes to any lost pool??

Comment: If the address is invalid, then the transaction must be reverted, and you should receive your money back automatically. It would be weird if you didn't get your money back automatically. Could you please share your transaction hash so that we can check it out?

Comment: Being Said invalid address no hash transaction have been created... Also the funds not reversed for wrong address.. my trading platform in coinformat

Comment: If there is no transaction hash, then the funds may still be in your account. In this case, you should contact your platform's support team to inquire about the issue. Hope you find the solution to your problem. Good luck